# Date range and naive datetime throw Runtimewarning

Tags: python, django

Given the date range for today to filter for an entry in Django:

```
today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(timezone.now(), datetime.time.min)
today_max = datetime.datetime.combine(timezone.now(), datetime.time.max)
today_events = Entry.objects.filter(due_date_time__range=(today_min, today_max))
```

I am clearly using `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.date.today()`, in order to consider the timezone support, but still I get the error messages:

```
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-13 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-13 23:59:59.999999) while time zone support is active.
```

What am I overlooking? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the sources of the datetime module in Python 3.2, result of datetime.datetime.combine is constructed like this:

```
@classmethod
def combine(cls, date, time):
    ...

    return cls(date.year, date.month, date.day,
               time.hour, time.minute, time.second, time.microsecond,
               time.tzinfo)
```

So the tzinfo is not honoured here, the way you use the combine function (if the Python 2.X version of datetime does it the way the 3.2 version does).

To get a localized datetime object, Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#usage) recommend this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```